# How to create a job for queue:work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a job to send emails when the user registers in the application.

SendWelcomeEmail.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendWelcomeEmail extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $user = &$this->user;

        $message = sprintf('Hello %s', $user->name);

        $mailer->raw($message, function ($m) use ($user){
            $m->from('lucas.nuck@gmail.com', 'Lucas Lopes');
            $m->to($user->email, $user->name);
        });
    }
}
```

I would like to create a job to execute the php artisan queue: work command every minute to send the emails that are in the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be to set up Supervisor.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#supervisor-configuration, it will automatically restart your  queue:work process if it fails.

To solve the confusion for you:

In `app/Console/Kernel.php` file, inside the schedule function you would add a command that you want to be ran at a specific interval. An example would be :
`$schedule->command('SendFailedLoginsReport')->weekly()->mondays()->at('03:00');`

On your server, you can add your cron like this
`* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to run the queue daemon, not run a command. You need to do this within your server environment, not using laravels scheduled commands.

You could use something like Linux's `screen` to place your command in.

This will consinuiously poll your queue server for new jobs, then process them.

Comment: Do not need to set the command in the `app/Console/Kernel.php` how often will it be executed?